# Data Annotations in which layer? DAL, BLL or UI?

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations

This is how I use to to. I use Data Annotations on the Entity Framework layer, that will then be available in Razor, generating client and server side validations.

Any reason to use them in the Business Logic Layer Objects or View Model Objects of the UI layer?

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way :

1- Annotations that are related to `Database structure` , I put them on my `Entity models` in DAL
2- Annotations that are related to user `input validation` , I put them on `view models` in UI

`BLL` has nothing to do with Database structure or UI validation.

using `Entity models` directly in `views` is not recommended. It's better to have a `viewModel` for each view.